# Pass values of setOnDateChangeListener to DATABASE_NAME

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

How to pass the value of setOnDateChangeListener to DATABASE_NAME?

I formatted my dbhelper like this

```
public static String getDateTime() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyyMMdd", Locale.getDefault());
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = getDateTime();
```

While I formatted my calendar setOnDateChangeListener just like how I formatted my DATABASE_NAME.

Below is my repo class which gets the sum(Fats) from the date today.
What I want is to get the sum(Fats) from the date I clicked on the calendar.

```
public double totalFatB(){

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        String query = "SELECT SUM(Fat) FROM " +breakfast.TABLE;

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        c.moveToFirst();
        double i=c.getDouble(0);

        return i;

    }
```

Here is my onDateChangeListener

```
CalendarView calendarView=(CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month,
                                            int dayOfMonth) {
                month = month+1;
                if ((month == 1) || (month == 2)|| (month == 3)|| (month == 4)|| (month == 5)|| (month == 6)|| (month == 7)|| (month == 8)|| (month == 9) )
                {
                    String m= "0"+month;
                    if ((dayOfMonth == 1) || (dayOfMonth == 2)|| (dayOfMonth == 3)|| (dayOfMonth == 4)|| (dayOfMonth == 5)|| (dayOfMonth == 6)|| (dayOfMonth == 7)|| (dayOfMonth == 8)|| (dayOfMonth == 9) ) {
                        String d = "0" + dayOfMonth;
                         date= year +""+ m +""+ d;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),date, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + year + m + d, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
                    }
                        else
                        {
                             date= year +""+ m +""+ dayOfMonth;
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),date, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + year + m + dayOfMonth, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
                        }
                }
                else if ((dayOfMonth == 1) || (dayOfMonth == 2)|| (dayOfMonth == 3)|| (dayOfMonth == 4)|| (dayOfMonth == 5)|| (dayOfMonth == 6)|| (dayOfMonth == 7)|| (dayOfMonth == 8)|| (dayOfMonth == 9) ) {
                    String d = "0" + dayOfMonth;
                     date= year +""+ month +""+ d;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),date, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + year + month + d, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
                }
                    else
                {
                    date= year +""+ month +""+ dayOfMonth;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),date, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + year + month + dayOfMonth, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: You only need one database total, not one per day. Name it "meals". You can query using the date later.

Comment: But if you want help, show the `setOnDateChangeListener` method. See about a [mcve]

Comment: Hello sir cricket, Okay, I will make one database for that, but how can i pass the value of my **onSelectedDayChange** to be the reference of what date will my dbhelper get the data. By the way sir, ive edited my post and included my onSelectedDayChange.

Answer (score 1):

> How to pass the value of setOnDateChangeListener to DATABASE_NAME?

Simply put - you shouldn't do this. If you did, that means you have one database file per day, and that is causing overhead in your application data.

Besides that, a SQLiteOpenHelper class only looks at the  Database name string when it is constructed, so if you had multiple names, you be recreating that object for each date and that wears out the memory/battery of your device.

In theory, it's possible...

```
@Override
public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month,
                                        int dayOfMonth) {
    // Build a Calendar
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    // c.set(); // TODO: Set year, month, dayOfMonth 
    ...
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyyMMdd", Locale.getDefault());

    // Get a database by name
    String DATABASE_NAME = dateFormat.format(c.getTime());
    SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DATABASE_NAME , null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    // TODO: Query 'db'
```

But I would not recommend it.

---

Instead, you can use **one** master database and [store a date column (as a TEXT or INT) within your SQLlite table](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype)

Then,  you can do `public double totalFatB(Date date)`, or pass `(year, month, day)` directly and build a `WHERE` statement to filter for a particular day from the `setOnDateChangeListener` method.

Also, please use `SimpleDateFormat` again in that method to correctly build a date string, as shown. If statements are very verbose.

Comment: Ah, you mean sir that i need to make a only one database_name? I cant do that sir, because I have so many tables and columns inside it i think inside 1 database_name has 10tables and inside that tables has 15columns. Please teach me sir how to fetch the database_name using **setOnDateChangeListener** You are my only chance to do this sir.

Comment: If your problem is column count, then you're likely duplicating data and you need a better database design, but that's too much broad to answer here

Comment: Sorry sir, my bad. Im newbie sir in terms of sqlite and android studio, But is my idea possible sir? Because I think sir it will take about 3 days for me  to reformat my codes. If my idea is possible, Please teach me sir.

Comment: Im not particular with column count sir. But my problem is I need to pass the  **setOnDateChangeListener** to be the reference what DATABASE_NAME will my app will fetch.

Comment: 1) No need to call me sir 2) I don't think your idea is possible (at least not by using a SQLiteOpenHelper class) because that has to be created **before** your date selection using some existing name 3) You have the opportunity to learn about correct database design, so however long that takes is worth it

Comment: Please teach me how proper database designing. I really need your help.

Comment: How to make a database effectively.

Comment: Please help me to conceptualize the best database structure for my application.

Comment: I've already given my suggestion. But  1)  I'm not in charge of your application, it's your decision to follow my advice or not 2) that's too broad to answer here anyway 3)  Just make each table that needs a date have one column added, and that's it. Your queries then need updated, of course. That doesn't take 3 days.

Comment: Ive already reformated my codes, my question for now sir is how can i pass the value of **setOnDateChangeListener ** ? i dont know how to explain this, But how to reformat TotalFatB like what i posted to get the **setOnDateChangeListener **?

Comment: Have you done `public double totalFatB(Date date)` like I explained? Can you get `dbHelper` inside of `setOnDateChangeListener`, if so, then that's all you need. If you want help with just that, please create a new post with what you've tried related to those steps

Comment: Im banned from posting questions again, So i make a new account. By the way, I tried to do as what you told but i have problem with the date format, The full question is on here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42204697/how-to-pass-onselecteddaychange-to-act-as-reference-for-dbhelper

Comment: You can read over the help center about posting quality questions, not ones with really obvious solutions if you'd take the time to think about the tools you're using. Like the one you just linked to. 1) A SQL tutorial would do you good. 2) Maybe some additional understanding of Java?

Comment: Bye the way, I edited my post on that link because I tried something that seems to be easy but it show error.

Comment: Well, yeah. You toString-d a `allfood` object. You added the whole  object to a String, not a date. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4