# SQLiteException using WHERE " +KEY_Date+"='"+date+"'"

Tags: java, android, sql, android-sqlite

This is on my selectedDayChange on my mainactivity.java

```
date= year +""+ month +""+ dayOfMonth;

                    allfood food = new allfood();
                    food.Date="DATE_"+date;
                    double a = repo.totalFat(food);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" +a, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

While this is on my repo.java

```
public double totalFat(allfood date){


        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper1.getReadableDatabase();

        String query = "SELECT SUM(Fat) FROM " +allfood.TABLE+ " WHERE " +KEY_Date+"="+date;

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        c.moveToFirst();
        double i=c.getDouble(0);

        return i;

    }
```

Then it shows an error, by the way, I know I needed to make something like this: `KEY_Date+"='"+date+"'"`

```
String query = "SELECT SUM(Fat) FROM " +allfood.TABLE+ " WHERE " +KEY_Date+"='"+date+"'";
```

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error (code
>   1): , while compiling: SELECT SUM(Fat) FROM allfood WHERE
>   Date=info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.Overall.allfood@1cbb35e1

This line

> Date=info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.Overall.allfood@1cbb35e1

should be

> Date=DATE_20170213

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Don't add a literal `allfood` object to a String. SQL can't interpret a Java object.

The method should be any of the following because `allfood` is the whole object, you do need it as the parameter. And naming it as `date` is simply confusing.

- `totalFat(Date date)`
- `totalFat(String date)`
- `totalFat(Calendar date)`
- `totalFat(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)`

> should be
>   Date=DATE_20170213

2) No, it really shouldn't because [Sqlite does not support that format of dates](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). Additionally, pre-pending `DATE_` is just wasting storage in your database.

3) Please do not use this

```
date= year +""+ month +""+ dayOfMonth
```

Build a `Calendar` object and use `SimpleDateFormat` to correctly get a date formatted string.

using the last option above, you'd have something like this

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);
String queryForDate = fmt.format(calendar.getTime());
// db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, new String[] {...  // TODO: Complete this
```

Comment: I read at somewhere that columns doesnt accept all number like 20170213 (Which is the date today) so I added "DATE_" But as what you've said, i reformatted my date as 2017-02-13, I have the same error, I think i need to wrap or pass the value. What do you think?

Comment: Oh, sorry I types really slow, wait sir, im gonna use the code you suggested

Comment: Don't just copy paste what I have. Try to understand why I'm doing it

Comment: OMG! You are a lifesaver! My code works! I really awe you a lot. Ive been struggling for almost 2 days just for this! Thankyou again sir. I hope I will be as good as you in terms of programming. Thankyou again sir!